# What would be the best way to parse HTML pages with Codename One?

Tags: codenameone

I'd like to parse HTML to read information from web pages where no service is available.

With JavaSE I'd probably use jsoup and a HTML sanitizer to make the HTML well-formed and to filter out irrelevant portions before processing the intermediate format as XML.

However it is not that simple to use arbitrary libraries with Codename One because the runtime does not have the full scope of JavaSE.

Has anybody done HTML parsing using Codename One and what would be the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

The builtin `XMLParser` in Codename One can parse HTML even when formed as SGML (incorrectly formed XML). It should produce good enough results.

Alternatively you can use the `BrowserComponent` to load the HTML with JavaScript and use DOM queries to parse the data, I think this might be even possible without showing the component but I'm not 100% sure about that.